# Kafka Streams "Suppressed" feature causes OOM / heavy GC

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka Streams 2.1 and created the following stream using Suppressed feature to process the aggregation of each whole minute:

```
originStream
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(60)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
    .aggregate(factory::createAggregation,
        (k, v, a) -> a.aggregate(v),
        materialized.withLoggingDisabled())
    .suppress(untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream();
```

The rate of messages I receive is about 200 per second.
After a short time I see the GC starting to work very hard, and sometimes OOM errors.

Since I use a heap of 2GB and a record will not take more than 1KB, it is clear to me that something is wrong - there shouldn't be so many messages in a window of 1 minute to explode a 2GB heap.

So.. I took a heap dump, in which I see 5 `InMemoryTimeOrderedKeyValueBuffer` Objects taking more than 300MB each (total >1.5GB).

I dived some more into one of those, and saw that the smallest/highest timestamp in their sortedMap was 1,575,458,160,000/1,575,481,800,000. This means that the buffer holds messages during a period of 23,640,000 = 394 minutes.

To my understanding the buffer was supposed to be flushed, so that only the last minute will consume the memory - all other windows should have been evicted.

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should not be `suppress()` but the aggregation state store. By default, it has a retention time of 1 day. You can reduce the retention time by passing in `Materialized.withRetention(...)` into `aggregate()`.

I am surprised that your heap dump shows `InMemoryTimeOrderedKeyValueBuffer` though, because this is the store used by `suppress()`. Hence, I am not 100% sure if reducing the retention time will fix the issue.

Btw: that there are a few bugs in `suppress()` in 2.1 version that are only fixed in 2.3 release and thus it's highly recommended to upgrade to 2.3 if you use `suppress()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed The BufferConfig to use max-bytes boundary:

```
Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded().withMaxBytes(10_000_000)
```

and that seem to solve the problem. I looked at the code, and don't understand why - because I see it now should have thrown an exception, but it doesn't.

So, I still don't understand something here, but the problem is solved for now.

After that I used Mattias J. Sax suggestions too, just to be even safer (Thanks).

**Edit:**

It happened again twice today. This means that what I did did not fix the problem (Although it may have changed its frequency).

Right now, I have no solution for this problem.

Comment: having the same issue, did you ever figured this out ?